# How do I expand a variable as an argument to a highlight command?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

In the context of a Vim plugin, I would like to add the ability to customise highlight colours.

How do I expand the variable in a scenario like the following:

```
    get s:cursorline_bg = get(g:, 'customcolours_cursorline_bg', 'black')
    hi CursorLine cterm=NONE ctermbg=s:cursorline_bg
```

As it stands this gives an error as the variable is being literally interpreted as the word 's:cursorline_bg' and not the value 'black'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to construct a string and interpret it using [`execute`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#:execute):

```
exe 'hi CursorLine cterm=NONE ctermbg=' . s:cursorline_bg
```

Dot (`.`) is [string concatenation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#expr5) in `vim`.

Comment: @BenjaminRowell Glad to be helpful!